# Filter results dynamically in CloudWatch insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I want to dynamically omit some results from a query in CloudWatch insights.

Let's say I want to include only the results with the filtered request IDs from **query A** as below.

- query A

> ```
>  fields logMessage.0.reqId
>     | filter @message like 'LAMBDA_TEST'
> ```

- query B

> ```
>     filter @requestId in [{results from query A as a list}]
> ```

Do these kinds of queries possible in CloudWatch insights?

Comment: It is not possible to have a query referencing the output of another one, why not simply do the filter in the same query?

Comment: I am interested in updating the CloudWatch dashboard by dynamically removing some request ids. I want to filter out the logs generated by the lambda service it self (@type = REPORT)